# TestNg parallel tests/classes when using base test class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, parallel-processing, testng

I'm trying to run tests in parallel by using TestNg. I have 3 classes (two test classes which extend BaseTest class)

The BaseTest class has only "setup" stuff and "teardown", nothing else.

When i try to run tests in parallel like this, one class with tests runs and for other class only a browser is opened (but test isn't executed)

But!! when i cut code from BaseTest class and put it directly to each of my test classes (and thus not extending BaseClass) then the code works and tests run in parallel

why?? I'm not doing any code change at all... and when i wish to run tests not in parallel(just one by one), then using extend of BaseTest class works just fine

in testing.xml tried to put parallel="methods" "tests","true"...

below are my classes and testing.xml

---

```
public class BaseTest {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\files\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

-----------------------
public class HomePageHotelsSearchTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void giveNameProperly() throws IOException {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver, wait);

        homePage.openUrl("https://www.phptravels.net/");

        homePage.openHotelsSearchTab();
        homePage.inputCityInHotelsSearch("London");
        homePage.selectCityFromSearchResult(0);
        homePage.inputCheckInDateInHotelsSearch("23/08/2018");
        homePage.inputCheckOutDateInHotelsSearch("27/08/2018");
        homePage.openPeopleAmountTabInHotelsSearch();
        homePage.addAdultsInHotelsSearch(1);
        homePage.startSearchingHotels();
        homePage.elementClickable(By.linkText("Grand Plaza Apartments"));

        String firstResult = homePage.readText(By.linkText("Grand Plaza Apartments"));
        Assert.assertEquals("Grand Plaza Apartments", firstResult);

        //Reporter.log("Test owned!", true);

    }

}

-----------------------
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver, wait);

        homePage.openUrl("https://www.phptravels.net/");


        LoginPage loginPage = homePage.goToLoginPage();
        loginPage.waitForPageToLoad("Login");
        loginPage.inputEmail("user@phptravels.com");
        loginPage.inputPassword("demouser");

        loginPage.login();

        loginPage.waitForPageToLoad("My Account");

        String myAccountPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(myAccountPageTitle, "My Account");

        //Reporter.log("Test owned!", true);


    }

}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Suite" thread-count="2" parallel="true">
        <test name="test1">
            <classes>
                <class name="tests.LoginTest" />
                <class name="tests.HomePageHotelsSearchTest"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define TestNG annotation in each class which you will call to Execute. You can not define @BeforeClass @AfterClass annotation in BaseTest. What you can call is BaseTest method. Refer your code with Example:

```
public class BaseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    public void setup() {
        ....
    }

    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class HomePageHotelsSearchTest extends BaseTest {    

    @BeforeClass
    public void startTest(){
    setup(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void giveNameProperly() {
            ...
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void stopTest(){
    teardown();
    }
}
```

You can directly call BaseTest methods without object, As you have extend BaseTest class.

---

```
 public class HomePageHotelsSearchTest {

    BaseTest testObj = new BaseTest();

    @BeforeClass
    public void startTest(){
    testObj.setup(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void giveNameProperly() {
            ...
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void stopTest(){
    testObj.teardown();
    }    
 }
```

If you not extending BaseTest class, You need to call those method with reference to object.

Thus, in each class there must be @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotation, So TestNG will call it before @Test execution.

Comment: to call a static method we does not requires a class object, if we have ISA relation ship we can directly call it....
    BaseTest testObj = new BaseTest();
    testObj.setup(); 

method declaration inside base class is public static void setup() { }

Comment: @Amit You may check it by implement this scenario without object.

Comment: Compiler is showing this warning - The static method setup() from the type BaseTest should be accessed in a static way. Is it the standard way to access setUp and tearDown methods in PageFactory framework ?

Comment: There is no need to define Static method in BaseTest class. If static method has been define in BaseTest then it need to implement for all those method which are extending BaseTest Methods. Regarding object calling in derived class, This is basic example for Beginners. There are many more ways to call BaseTest Methods without defining in Derived class. Hope it make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Found one more issue. Cause both classes initiate static WebDriver object (with setup), then the first one which executes the teardown method, shuts webdriver object and thus other session can't continue

figuring now out how to change it properly

Comment: Everything is fine.... but I really not able to understand this 
If static method has been define in BaseTest then it need to implement for all those method which are extending BaseTest ==> Static method is same for all classes, they are never required to be overridden...
But yes this is true for interface methods which are must to be overridden by derived class, with java8 we can add static methods to interface.

Comment: @Redgard You have to make script method only in each clas, And you have to call those methods in single class where TestNG annotation has been defined.

Comment: @Redgard - This is the standard way of using PageFactory all tests executes independently and will have there own browser instance, usually browser sharing does not happens in PageFactory....

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for quick replies, it's working now :-)

Well, basically now BaseTest class has only methods to initiate/create webdriver objects and start browser session. Later test classes have their own instances of webdriver and use those methods to initiate them

Comment: Hi guys, i found even a simplier solution) 

Same code as I had at start but! just removed static words from WebDriver object and from methods, that's it :-)